# C# Class Inheritance Issue with Simple Calculator

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I am beginner to C# and am trying to get my second class, MyCalc2, to inherit from MyCalc. But I encounter the following error message in regards to MyCalc2:

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'x' of 'MyCalc.MyCalc(int, int, string, string)'

The goal here is to just add another class that inherits from the base class.

I know that I need to add something like 'MyCalc: base(x)' to my base class but am lost to where to place the parameter (if that is even the correct thing to do). Any guidance would be appreciated. Here is what I have so far:

```
    using System;
class MyCalc
{
    // class variable
    public int x;
    public int z;
    public string y;
    public string n;

    // constructor
    public MyCalc(int x, int z, string y, string n)
    {
        this.x = x;  // assign the parameter passed to the class variable
        this.z = z;
        this.y = y;
        this.n = n;

    }
    // calculate the operations
    public int GetAdd()
    {
        return (this.x + this.z);

    }

    public int GetSubtract()
    { 
        return (this.x - this.z);
    }

    public int GetMultiply()
    {
        return (this.x * this.z);
    }

    public int GetDivide()
    {
        return (this.x / this.z);
    }

    public string GetYes()
    {
        return (this.y);
    }

    public string GetNo()
    {
        return (this.n);
    }

}

class MyCalc2:MyCalc //where the error is occurring 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)



    {
        bool repeat = false;
        do
        {

            repeat = false;


            int x = 0; int z = 0; string y; string n;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the First Number");
            x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Second Number");
            z = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());



            //Using a switch statement to perform calculation:
            Console.WriteLine("Enter operator\r");
            switch (Console.ReadLine())


            {

                case "+":
                    Console.WriteLine($"The Answer is: {x} + {z} = " + (x + z));
                    break;

                case "-":
                    Console.WriteLine($"The Answer is: {x} - {z} = " + (x - z));
                    break;
                case "*":
                    Console.WriteLine($"The Answer is: {x} + {z} = " + (x + z));
                    break;

                case "/":
                    Console.WriteLine($"The Answer is: {x} - {z} = " + (x - z));
                    break;


            }



                //Repeat or Exit program using the do-while loop:

            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want another operation(Y / N) ?");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            repeat = (input.ToUpper() == "Y");

        }
            while (repeat);
            Console.WriteLine("Thanks for using our system.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why is `MyCalc2` inheriting from `MyCalc`? It doesn't extend or override any of `MyCalc`'s methods. I suspect you want to use a `new MyCalc(something)` inside your `MyCalc2`, not inherit from it.

Comment: You may need to rethink your design, inheritance is probably not a good fit here.

Comment: You probably should not include the method Main as a member of MyClass2. Did you do this intentionally? Inheritance should be reserved very strictly to situalations where you can say "Childclass is an ParentClass" In all other situations it probably is not a good idea to use inheritance. I suggest to just kick the line MyVals2:MyCalc out, make sure all aprentesis match. You probably try to create a console application. Main is the entrypoint and it may run fine.

Answer (score 0):

MyCalc2 does not have a way of initializing MyCalc (Base Class) Because in your BaseClass you do not have a parameter less constructor.

Solution:

1. Add a param less constructor in Base Class
2. Add a constructor in Derived class which has a way of calling base class constructor

for your code below should work:

```
class MyCalc2 : MyCalc
{
    public MyCalc2 () : base(0, 0, "", "")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MyCalc2` has no explicit constructor.  Which means it has only one *implicit* constructor which takes no arguments and sets no values.  If made explicitly it would look like this:

```
public MyCalc2()
{

}
```

However, `MyCalc` *does* have an explicit constructor.  Which means it has *no* implicit constructor.  And its constructor *does* take arguments:

```
public MyCalc(int x, int z, string y, string n)
{
    this.x = x;  // assign the parameter passed to the class variable
    this.z = z;
    this.y = y;
    this.n = n;
}
```

So when you create an instance of `MyCalc2` it has no way of providing any values to `MyCalc`.  You essentially have three options:

1. Add a constructor to `MyCalc` (you can have as many constructors as you want, as long as the parameters differ) which takes no parameters.  However, in that case the class-level values for `MyCalc` would all be default values.  You'd have to set them explicitly after constructing the object.<sup>1</sup>
2. Add a constructor to `MyCalc2` which accepts those values and passes them to the parent constructor, or at least passes default values to the parent constructor.
3. Don't use inheritance here.

Honestly, in this case I'd go with the third option.  What is inheritance meant to accomplish here?  `MyCalc2` isn't meaningfully an instance of `MyCalc`.  All it does it hold the initial entry point of the application (the `Main` method), and that's really all it should do.

The logic in your `Main` method should create and use an instance of `MyCalc`, but the class which has that `Main` method shouldn't try to *be* an instance of `MyCalc`.  That will only cause more confusion than solve any meaningful problems.

---

<sup>1</sup> Side Note: Public class fields are historically a bad habit to get into in object-oriented programming.  There's a variety of talk on the subject, and you'll see this often as you continue in your experience.  In general you want your objects to expose *behaviors*, not *values*.  The methods on the object look somewhat Java-like in convention.  For C# conventions consider using properties (which compile down to methods themselves, the syntax is just semantically different).  You can have `{ get; set; }` auto-properties for the values themselves, and explicit read-only `{ get { /*...*/ } }` properties for the calculated values.

Comment: It's called fields, not 'class level variables'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. There are two classes MyClass, for the calculator (you may want to rename it) and Propram. Program holds just the method Main, which get your program started. It works like this, but there are some bugs left. I leave it to you to fix them. Except that you miss a clear understanding of the concepts class and inheritance, your code is not too bad for a beginner. It is almost working.

```
using System;

namespace TestCalculator
  {
 class MyCalc
{
// class variable
public int x;
public int z;
public string y;
public string n;

// constructor
public MyCalc(int x, int z, string y, string n)
  {
  this.x = x;  // assign the parameter passed to the class variable
  this.z = z;
  this.y = y;
  this.n = n;

  }
// calculate the operations
public int GetAdd()
  {
  return (this.x + this.z);

  }

public int GetSubtract()
  {
  return (this.x - this.z);
  }

public int GetMultiply()
  {
  return (this.x * this.z);
  }

public int GetDivide()
  {
  return (this.x / this.z);
  }

public string GetYes()
  {
  return (this.y);
  }

public string GetNo()
  {
  return (this.n);
  }

}
 class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
  {
  bool repeat = false;
  do
    {

    repeat = false;


    int x = 0; int z = 0; string y; string n;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the First Number");
    x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Second Number");
    z = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());



    //Using a switch statement to perform calculation:
    Console.WriteLine("Enter operator\r");
    switch (Console.ReadLine())


      {

      case "+":
        Console.WriteLine($"The Answer is: {x} + {z} = " + (x + z));
        break;

      case "-":
        Console.WriteLine($"The Answer is: {x} - {z} = " + (x - z));
        break;
      case "*":
        Console.WriteLine($"The Answer is: {x} + {z} = " + (x + z));
        break;

      case "/":
        Console.WriteLine($"The Answer is: {x} - {z} = " + (x - z));
        break;


      }



    //Repeat or Exit program using the do-while loop:

    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want another operation(Y / N) ?");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    repeat = (input.ToUpper() == "Y");

    }
  while (repeat);
  Console.WriteLine("Thanks for using our system.");
  Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

}

Comment: @Pedicellaria Can you please let us know if we helped you solve your problem? You may mark one of the solutions as answer or helpful.